# Configuring activemq client for using ssl for encryption only

Tags: ssl, jms, activemq-classic

I was wondering if I can set an activemq broker with a ssl connection with the sole purpose of encryption (similar to HTTPS considering that the client does not check the certificate).

In that sense, I've tried seting up the broker to use ssl connection, set its keystore and on.

And on the client side, I tried using the sample code from [fusesource](http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.5/security/FMQSecuritySSLClients.html) as basis but without setting the client trust store (I would like the client to accept every certificate).

With that configuration, I could not connect the client and I got the following error message in the broker's log:

> 2013-05-06 15:25:32,848 | ERROR | Could not accept connection :
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key
>   corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled. |
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ Transport
>   Server: ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?trace=true

Is this error really because the client has not added the broker certificate to its truststore? If so, is there a way so that the client accept the connection even without a truststore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my SSL configuration in the broker which caused that error message. I am not sure exactly what was wrong because I have re-done the whole configuration following this [tutorial](http://www.jmkg.co.uk/2010/08/24/a-network-of-ssl-connected-activemq-brokers/) and got it to run the broker without errors.

In order to get the ssl encryption but no authentication, I basically had to set my ssl connection to `<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?trace=true?needClientAuth=false"/>` 
and to either

- add the certificate directly to the JVM as in [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)
- or create a trust manager that accept all certificates on the client as in [Setting trust store programatically in ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory seems to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747902/setting-trust-store-programatically-in-activemqsslconnectionfactory-seems-to-fai)